# Problem in creating installer for 64 bit system

Tags: c#, vsto, x86-64

I am working on a c# +vsto project.We create and validate excel templates using the vsto.
I recently found 1 interesting thing.

On 32 bits system,software gets installed in

> C:\Program Files

But on the 64 bit system,
it gets installed in

> C:\Program Files (x86)

when i try

**Case I:
opening excel file ( which was created on 32 bit system) on 64 bit system.**

**Case II:
opening excel file ( which was created on 64 bit system) on 32 bit system**

I get an exception on the system.

This is because the respective DLL's are stored at the different locations.

as 32 bit refers to

> C:\Program Files

and 64 bit refers to

> C:\Program Files (x86)

Is there any way  i can force installer to install software in **C:\Program Files** for 64 bit system rather than  installing it in the **C:\Program Files (x86)**

Any help ?

regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention is to install 32 bit software to `Program Files (x86)` on a 64 bit system.  I don't think you want to install your 32 bit software to `Program Files` – that would go against the grain.

As to what the fix is, I wonder why Excel thinks your DLLs are installed in `Program Files`. Is it possible that you are using hard-coded paths somewhere?

---

From your comment to this answer it does indeed appear that you are hard-coding the installation path. This sounds like it could be a problem in many ways.  You've discovered the 64 bit OS issue, but what if your user's system drive is D?  And what if they have a localized version of Windows?  In Germany, for example, the program files folder is typically `C:\Programme`.

From what I can glean on how to deploy a VSTO add-in you simply write a bunch of registry keys which include details of where the DLL is located.  My guess is that you currently have this location hard-coded and you need to change your installer to write the location based on the location that the user chooses when installing the VSTO.

Comment: When i install my application on 32 bit system and generate template it stores path of the DLL in the  template,but when i try opening that excel template on 64 bit system ,it searches for the  DLL reference present in *Program Files* but the  DLL is present in the *Program Files(x86)* folder and i get an exception I hope its clear now..

Comment: You should use the special folder classes in .net to locate the program files directory. Even if you put it in `Program Files`, it could fail if the user's system drive is `D` and so the program files folder is `D:\Program Files`. And what about non English installations which have localized names. Best practice would be to write a registry entry when installing saying where your DLLs files were installed to and loading them from that location.

Comment: @ David : How the Excel template will locate the respective DLL reference  from  the registry ?

Comment: @Sangram I don't know. I don't know VSTO. How does it locate the DLL at the moment?  If it's anything like a COM add-in then the installer writes registry keys appropriate to the location where the VSTO DLLs have just been copied.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand the querstion but couldn't you just use System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem to see if this a 64-bit OS?

Answer (score 0):

From this comment....

> When i install my application on 32
>   bit system and generate template it
>   stores path of the DLL in the
>   template,but when i try opening that
>   excel template on 64 bit system ,it
>   searches for the DLL reference present
>   in Program Files but the DLL is
>   present in the Program Files(x86)
>   folder and i get an exception I hope
>   its clear now.

It sounds like maybe you're not quite using VSTO properly, though there may be a usage I'm unaware of.

With typical VSTO addins, the addin is registered under the EXCEL "Addins" key. It won't matter whether it's 64 or 32 bit, you'll still only have one (which ever is applicable) registered.

The addin will load when Excel loads, NOT when you load a specific template.

When you load a template, the addin typically monitors for the doc load and then reacts as appropriate.

I believe there is a "per document" type of addin you can build with VSTO, but if you do that, it wouldn't surprise me at all that Excel would fail to load the doc across different install types of Excel, since they aren't automatically compatible.